# Plot for unbiasedness

Tags: probability, data-visualization, unbiased-estimator

I was reading a paper and the authors describe a plot which they used to determine whether their estimator was unbiased. This plot is described as follows (verbatim):

> To assess if the probabilities of taxonomic placement were unbiased, we ordered the classification probabilities from lowest to highest, and computed a cumulative sum of both these probabilities as well as the indicator variables describing whether the outcome predicted with highest probability was a correct one. We then plotted these two cumulative sums against each other. If the classification probabilities are unbiased, such a plot should follow the identity line.

Is there a specific name for this type of plot? Is there a reference which describes the theory justifying this plot?

Source:
Somervuo, P., et al. "Quantifying uncertainty of taxonomic placement in DNA barcoding and metabarcoding." Methods in Ecology and Evolution (2017): 398-407.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a [qq-plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) to me.  It's most typically used to compare the distributions of two samples (e.g., groups), or to compare a sample to a theoretical distribution (e.g., the normal).  (It may help you to read my answer to: [PP-plots vs. QQ-plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100383/7290).)  I gather they have ordered categorical distributions, and they are plotting the ECDFs ([empirical cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)) against each other.  If I'm not misunderstanding, what they did seems pretty reasonable to me, although using an [agreement chart](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/219245/7290) might be better.